# Add options to select using a object's key and values in javascript?

Tags: javascript, loops, object

I need to iterate the folowing object in javascript in order to populate a select option:

```
{"options":{"116":{"pt":"116","en":"116"},"118":{"pt":"118","en":"118"}}}
```

My actual code is this:

```
for (var key in data) {
   if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      var opt = document.createElement('option');
      opt.innerHTML = data[key];
      opt.value = data[key];
      sel.appendChild(opt);
   }
}
```

The above loop gives me all of the elements in the array.
But what i want to do is to only pick the value of the 'pt' keys.
My loop must return only 116 and 118 from the 'pt' keys.

Comment: So `data` is the `options` object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to do `data[key].pt`:

```js
var obj = {
  "options": {
    "116": {
      "pt": "116",
      "en": "116"
    },
    "118": {
      "pt": "118",
      "en": "118"
    }
  }
};
var data = obj.options;
var sel = document.getElementById('select');
for (var key in data) {
  if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.innerHTML = data[key].pt;
    opt.value = data[key].pt;
    sel.appendChild(opt);
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="select"></select>
```

Comment: I like this as it's changing to a minimum the original question.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this using [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) and [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```js
const data = {"options":{"116":{"pt":"116","en":"116"},"118":{"pt":"118","en":"118"}}}

const sel = document.getElementById('select');

const ptValues = Object.values(data.options)
                        .forEach(v => {
                            var opt = document.createElement('option');
                            opt.innerHTML = opt.value = v.pt
                            sel.appendChild(opt);
                          })
```

```html
<select id="select"></select>
```

Comment: This is not a optimal solution as this is adding an extra looping to filter the `pt` values. Instead, you can do on the same loop while creating the `option`.

Comment: I was typing the `option` code and updating that :)